# Configure Keep Alive for connections coming from Cloudflare

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, cloudflare

I have two servers, an NGINX load balancer that receives connections from Cloudflare and two Apache applications that receive requests forwarded by NGINX.

[Cloudflare] → [NGINX] → [Apache 01/Apache 02]

My Apache server will only be accessed through NGINX, and NGINX only accepts HTTP/HTTPs connections coming from Cloudflare.

By default NGINX always sends the user to the same Apache server he visited the first time (limitations due to background upload).

I already have Apache configured with Keep Alive.
Should I also configure NGINX to keep connections alive?

Comment: Yes, you need to explicitly enable keep alive to the upstream servers. For inward connections to nginx, this is enabled by default. Sticky sessions are a design time defect.

Comment: @symcbean So both in Apache and NGINX I have to enable Keep Alive. That?

Comment: With a short network hop there's not huge gains to be made, but yes it needs to be enabled at both ends to work